# iOS 11 App update size information

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore

My iPad has just been updated to iOS 11. The new app store doesn’t seem to show the download size of each update any more.

[image]

[image]

As you can see in iOS 10, the size is really easy to spot in both the list and details view.

How can I find out the size of the updates so I don’t use too much data?

Comment: Isn’t the size in the app details page relevant to the total size of the app and not the upgrade size ?

Comment: @Jay Quite possibly. On my Android phone, it actually tells you "Size of update", which is usually tiny compared to the size of the whole app.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to click each app icon to get to the full description, then scroll down to where it shows the size.

Comment: I've already done that and seen nothing relevant. Would you care to post a screenshot?

Comment: Click the app icon in the updates list - this gets you to the app page, then scroll down past What's New, Preview, Ratings & Reviews, to Information - Size is the second item there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]
As you can see, the initial view does not give the information. It is hidden half way down the page, neither at the top or the bottom where you would expect to find it, and it is hidden in the visual noise of other information.